# Why do I need to ssh to be able to connect to Django's dev webserver?

Tags: python, django, ssh

I've set up a Django server on a virtual box running Scientific Linux.

I am starting the server with:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

this should in theory allow access from any IP. Well I am not able to view that page at `http://box:8000`.

By running:

```
ssh –L 8000:box:8000 user@box
```

the page shows up at `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Have you checked that `http://box:8000` is not firewalled?

Comment: Well IT says it's not. I can only take their word :)